# x values as interval to y value

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have this data

```
   10,000  12,350   11153        
   12,350  17,380   39524        
   17,380  24,670   29037    
   24,670  36,290   25469
```

By using matplotlib.pyplot I would like to draw a bar chart where bar starts at column0 and ends at column1. A bar would represent an interval (10 - 12.35) and bar height is column2 (1153). How could this be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can find documentation for `pyplot.bar()` [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar). For your question, you need to assign your column0 to `left`, your column2 to `height` and use column1-column0 for `width`:

```
import io

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = """10000 12350 11153
12350 17380 39524
17380 24670 29037
24670 36290 25469"""

df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(s), sep=' ', header=None, dtype='int')
plt.bar(df[0], df[2], df[1]-df[0])
plt.show()
```

[image]